# Does an interval inside a set contain an element no explicitly listed on the interval?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is {$\pi$} and element,subset, or neither of the interval {[1,4]}.

my  confusion is, $\pi$ is in the interval so does that make it an element and thus a subset of {[1,4]}?

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{\pi\}$ contains a single element, the real number (or Greek letter) $\pi$. It is not a real number (or Greek letter) itself, just a set containing one.

The set $\{[1, 4]\}$ contains a single element, the interval $[1, 4]$. Similarly, it is not an interval.

The set $\{\pi\}$ is not equal to the interval $[1, 4]$, so it is not an element of the set $\{[1, 4]\}$. The number $\pi$ is also not equal to the interval, so the set containing it is not a subset of the set containing the interval.

However, the interval $[1, 4]$ *does* contain the number $\pi$ in it, so $\{\pi\}$ *is* a *subset* of the interval $[1, 4]$, in the sense that all elements of the set are contained within the interval.

EDIT to expand:

The interval $[1, 4]$ is a set containing all real (presumably) numbers between 1 and 4, i.e. it is equivalent to the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\ |\ 1 \leq x \leq 4\}$. $\pi$ is a real number between 1 and 4, so it is an element of the set, i.e. $\pi \in [1, 4]$.

Set $A$ is a subset of set $B$ ($A \subseteq B$) if every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$. So the set $\{\pi\}$ is a subset of any set that contains $\pi$. The interval $[1, 4]$ is a set that contains $\pi$, so $\{\pi\} \subseteq [1, 4]$.

However, the set $\{[1, 4]\}$ does *not* contain $\pi$, it contains something that is not equal to $\pi$ (because it's another set), so $\{\pi\} \nsubseteq \{[1, 4]\}$.

Comment: So what you are saying is {$\pi$} is not equal to [1,4] because of this is not an element. :/ Can't believe I miss that.Also for the second part you are saying that {$\pi$} is not a subset of  {[1,4]} because  the set that contains {$\pi$} is not contained in {[1,4]}. Is this correct?   Regarding the last comment you made. So you are saying that given $\pi$ and [1,4] and asked about their relation one could say that \$pi$ is indeed a subset of [1,4]??

Comment: I'll spell things out a little more for you in an edit.